# c# .dbf gets random encoding with jet 4.0

Tags: c#, dbf, jet

I have got some old *.dbf files, which contains data encoded in windows-1257 encoding. 
I am opening dbf files with OleDBConnection with following connection string:

```
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
               filePath
               + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV";
```

Very odly is fact, that after reading file into `DataSet` object, its being extra encoded in `ISO-8859-1` encoding. So when i put it on winforms textBox, i was getting some weird simbols as Ō. After finding out that data has been coverted to  `ISO-8859-1`, used this, to convert back it to 1257 and this actually helped me:

```
Encoding from = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding to = Encoding.GetEncoding(1257);

foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataSet.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataSet.Columns)
    {
        if (dataColumn.DataType != typeof(string) || dataRow[dataColumn] == DBNull.Value)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dataRow[dataColumn] = to.GetString(from.GetBytes(dataRow[dataColumn].ToString()));
    }
}
```

But once i used this code on another PC, it `DataSet` object started to encode it self in different encoding (not 8859-1). I have no clue to to stop it, or control it, or at least to change it to encoding i want.

I have tried to compare Jet/4.0/ windows registers. I have checked pc language and region settings. Any tips or help appreciated.

Comment: I thought it should help me, but so far no luck. Not sure if CharacterSet even works for dbf files